# Elements child "shakes" when I increase the size with transition/animation

Tags: css

I have a circle here that increases with size when I hover over it. When I do that the "+" I have in the middle "shakes".

HTML

```
    <div class='test-ani'>
       <span>+</span>
    </div>
```

CSS (SCSS)

```
.test-ani {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;

    &:hover {
        transition: .5s;
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
    }

    span {
        color: #ffdb58;
        font-size: 50px;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

VISUAL GIF

[image]

Comment: Use transition on a parent

Comment: That just makes it so there is no transition for the circle though

Comment: issue is to due to justify-content and align-items  which is applied for the increased width and height

Comment: Naga I had also suspected that. However that is not the cause of this issue. When I remove those lines and replace it with absolute position it has the same effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animate transform rule:

```css
section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.test-ani {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.test-ani:hover {
  transition: transform .5s;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
.test-ani span {
  color: #ffdb58;
  font-size: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class='test-ani'>
     <span>+</span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Oh so it was because I had used transform already in the parent element?